# Cant set isSameSite to None in hapi-auth-cookie

Tags: hapi, hapi-auth-cookie

I am using hapi-auth-cookie version 7.0.0

Currently only `Lax Strict false` are available for isSameSite attribute, but I want to use `None` as well

Is there any workaround for solving this?